# Get touch event on an element which is initially hidden and then made visible on user action

Tags: react-native

My use case is to show a list of options under a text input when that text input is focused, like google autocomplete. The issue is that I can show/hide the list but the touch events on the list options are not firing.

The code is as follows:

```
renderListItem({item, index}){
    return <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#e6e6e6" activeOpacity={0.5} style={[styles.rowCont]} onPress={()=>this.handleListItemPress(item)}>
                <Text>{item.label}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
}

render() {
    let listPosition = this.props.positionObj; //View prop onlayout object.

    let resultDesign = this.props.visible ? 
    <View style={[styles.optionsCont, { top: listPosition.y + listPosition.height, left: listPosition.x }]}
        onStartShouldSetResponder={(event)=>{console.log("Setting responder..."); return true}}
        onResponderReject={(event)=>{console.log("The responder request is rejected.")}}
        onResponderTerminate={(event)=>{console.log("The responder has been taken from the View.")}}>
        <FlatList
            data={this.props.listData}
            renderItem={this.renderListItem}
            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        />
    </View>:
    <View/>;

    return resultDesign;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
},

optionsCont: {
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: 2,
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    borderRadius: 6,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#e6e6e6",
},  

rowCont: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#e6e6e6",
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
},
});
```

The responder props also never fire. I guess it is because the view is not rendered initially. Please suggest a way to achieve this. I prefer not to use a library unless if it is too time consuming to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Responder is failing to set because of

```
onStartShouldSetResponder={(event)=>{console.log("Setting responder..."); return true}}
```

Try changing that line to

```
onStartShouldSetResponder={()=>true}
```

I THINK, but am not 100% sure, that calling it the way you are does not actually invoke the anonymous function, therefore not setting the Responder.

You could also try to initialize a PanResponder and attach it to the View when the component mount using a constructor to circumvent the view not being rendered initially problem.

Comment: I tried calling `onStartShouldSetResponder` your way but it didn't work, however attaching a [PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder) to the view resolved the issue. Thanks!